# Exiting an AWK statement after printing a block of text

Tags: bash, macos, awk, scripting, text-manipulation

My problem is that I have a very large database (10GB) and I want to save as much time as possible searching through it.  I have an `awk` statement that is searching through the database and depending on the pattern, writes the data into another file.
I have an input file that will be fed into my script as a Terminal argument variable.  There are several lines of data within it that will be used as the pattern for the `awk` statement.
Within the database, all the lines that match the pattern are all sorted next to each other, so essentially, after printing, there is no need to search any further into the database cause everything has already been found.  Once the `awk` finds the first pattern matching line, all the other pattern matching lines are sequentially after it.

This problem is hard to explain with just words, so I've created a few examples of what my files, code, and the database look and operate like.

The input file via Terminal looks like this:

```
group_1
group_2
group_3
...
```

The 10GB database looks like this:

```
group_1 DATA ...
group_1 DATA ...
group_1 DATA ...
group_2 DATA ...
group_2 DATA ...
group_2 DATA ...
group_2 DATA ...
group_3 DATA ...
group_3 DATA ...
group_3 DATA ...
group_3 DATA ...
...
```

The script code with the `awk` statement in question looks like this:

```sh
IFS=$'\n'
set -f
for var in $(cat < "$1")
do  
    awk -v seq="$var" '{if (match($1, seq)) {print $0}}' filepath/database  > pattern_matched.file
done
```

a brief explanation of what this code is doing is that it takes in the Terminal argument variable, a filename in this case, and opens it up for the `for loop` to begin looping.  the pattern `group_1`, for example, is placed in `var` and the search through the database begins.  If the first column matches the pattern, it saves the line into the file `pattern_matched.file` file.

Currently, it searches through the entire 10GB worth of data and prints the data into the file as intended, but it wastes a lot of time.  After printing the lines that match the pattern, I want to stop the `awk` from continuing the search through the database and move on to the next pattern from the input file.  An example behavior for `group_2` would be the `awk` checking the first 3 lines of the database and sees that none of the lines have the matching pattern.  However, line 4 contains the pattern, so it prints the line and the subsequent pattern matching lines after it.  When the `awk` reaches line 8, it exits the `awk` statement and the `for loop` can then iterate to the next pattern to be searched for, `group_3`.

```sh
awk '{print $0; exit}' filename
```

Something like this does not work since it only prints the first instance and breaks out, I want something that can print all the matches and as soon as it finds the next non-pattern match, it breaks out.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
The current problem now is that the solution given below makes logical sense.  If it enters the if-statement, It would print the line into the file and iterate to the next line.  If the line did not match, it would enter the else-if statement and exit the `awk`.  This makes a lot of sense to me, but for some reason, once the `flag` variable has been set to 1 by the if-statement for the first matched line, it enters the else-if statement.  Since the else-if condition evaluates to true, it exits before even scanning the next line.  I confirmed this behavior with print statements everywhere in the `awk` statement.
This is my code with print statements:

```sh
awk -v seq="$seqid" '{if(match($1, seq)) {print "matched" ; print $1 ; flag=1} else if (flag) {print "not matched" ; exit}}'
```

which outputs this:
[weird behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulu1v.png)

Comment: Why not add `-v haveread=0` then your statement can be: `'{if (match($1, seq)) {print $0; haveread=1} else {haveread == 1 && exit}}'` (or something similar using a flag valraible) This will cause `awk` to `exit` on the first line after the sequence of lines it reads from. Before then, `haveread=0` and no action is taken in `else` clause.

Comment: by `haveread == 1 && exit` do you mean `haveread == 1 ; exit` ? there are some syntax issues.

Comment: Like `awk -v rd=0 '{ if ($1 == seq) {print $1;  rd = 1} else {if (rd == 1) exit }}'` (using `rd` for the flag)

Comment: This almost works.  It prints the first line and automatically hits the else-if and exits.  Why? I have no idea, the definition of else-if should have stopped it but I just confirmed it in my code:
`awk -v seq="$seqid" -v flag=0 '{if(match($1, seq)) {print $1 ; flag=1 } else {if(flag == 1) exit}}'`

Comment: @Lefty see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for why not to do [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802299/exiting-an-awk-statement-after-printing-a-block-of-text#comment100162077_56802299).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just read in the input file (`input_file`) into awk:

```
$ cat input_file
group_1
group_3
```

Awk script:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1 in a' input_file database
group_1 DATA ...
group_1 DATA ...
group_1 DATA ...
group_3 DATA ...
group_3 DATA ...
group_3 DATA ...
group_3 DATA ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shell code:

```
for var in $(cat < "$1")
do  
    awk 'script' filepath/database  > pattern_matched.file
done
```

is using an anti-pattern to read the input file stored in `$1`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, and will overwrite `pattern_matched.file` on every iteration of the loop. You should, I suspect, have written it as:

```
while IFS= read -r var
do  
    awk 'script' filepath/database  
done < "$1" > pattern_matched.file
```

Your awk code:

```
awk -v seq="$var" '{if (match($1, seq)) {print $0}}'
```

is using `match()` unnecessarily since you just want to do a regexp comparison and aren't using the variables that match() populates to help you isolate the matching string (RSTART/RLENGTH) and it's using a defult null condition and then puting the real condition in the action space and then hard-coding the default action of printing the current record. It's equivalent to just:

```
awk -v seq="$var" '$1 ~ seq'
```

but I'm not convinced you actually need a regexp comparison - given your example you should be doing a string comparison instead:

```
awk -v seq="$var" '$1 == seq'
```

Given your posted example may be misleading you'd just choose which of these is appropriate based on whether you want a regexp or string and partial or full match on $1:

```
awk -v seq="$var" '$1 == seq'              # full string
awk -v seq="$var" 'index($1,seq)'          # partial string
awk -v seq="$var" '$1 ~ ("^"seq"$")'       # full regexp
awk -v seq="$var" '$1 ~ seq'               # partial regexp
```

Let's say we go with that first full string match match, then to exit once the matching $1 has been processed would be:

```
awk -v seq="$var" '$1 == seq{print; f=1; next} f{exit}'
```

which would make your full code:

```
while IFS= read -r var
do  
    awk -v seq="$var" '$1 == seq{print; f=1; next} f{exit}'  filepath/database  
done < "$1" > pattern_matched.file
```

BUT I doubt if you need a shell loop at all and you could just do this instead:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seqs[$1]; next} $1 in seqs' "$1" filepath/database > pattern_matched.file
```

or some other variant that just has awk (or maybe just `join`) read the input files once. You can make the above exit after all `seqs[]` have been processed by:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { seqs[$1]; numSeqs++; next }
    $1 in seqs { print; if ($1 !== prev) numSeqs--; prev = $1; next }
    numSeqs == -1 { exit }
' "$1" filepath/database > pattern_matched.file
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
awk -v seq="$var" '{if (match($1, seq)) {print $0; found=1} else if (found) { exit }}'
```

Similar to David C. Rankin answer, but no need to pass the `rd=0` argument to awk since in awk any uninitialized variable is initialized to zero when its first used.

Comment: hmm, its the same situation as above, where after printing the first matching line and setting `found` to 1, its goes straight into the else-if statement and exits.  Perhaps something is very wrong with the rest of my code cause it to jump into the else-if statement????
I'm honestly stumped as to why the awk decides to enter the else-if statement if it has been in the if before it....

Comment: Weird. Would you like to check this example and see what's different in your case? https://pastebin.com/HjkyU3XJ

Comment: I took a look at the pastern, we basically have identical code, I sub'd it into my script and the output was:
`>1_AE00496_00001 
exit in 2 row
---
>2135_AE01682_00001 
exit in 13094 row
---`

ummmm

Comment: I executed the script here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php and the results are the ones expected.

Answer (score 0):

As we do not really know what you intend to do with your program, I will just give you an awk solution:

```
awk -v seq="$var" '($1!=seq) { if(p) exit; next }($1==seq){p=1}p'
```

This uses the flag `p` to check if it already met the sequence `seq`. A simple if condition determines if it should exit awk or move to the next record. Exiting is done after seq is found, moving to the next record is done before.

However, since you place this in a loop, this will read the file over and over and over again. If you want to make a subselection, you could use the solution of [James Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56803463/8344060)